# Copying files with python

Tags: python, image

I'm relatively new to python, and am part of the way through "Learning python the Hard Way," but have a question.

So, from what I've read, if you want to make a copy of a text file, you can just open and read it contents to a variable, then write this variable to a different file.  I've tested it out with images, and it actually seems to work.  Are there downsides to this method of copying that I'll run into later, and are there any file types it specifically *won't* work for?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`shutil.copyfile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) or [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) instead, which does this efficiently and correctly using a buffer.

Not that it is particularly hard, `shutil.copyfileobj()` is implemented as:

```
def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024):
    """copy data from file-like object fsrc to file-like object fdst"""
    while 1:
        buf = fsrc.read(length)
        if not buf:
            break
        fdst.write(buf)
```

This makes sure that your memory isn't filled up by a big file, by reading the file in chunks instead. Also, `.read()` is not guaranteed to return all of the data of the file, you could end up not copying all of the data if you don't loop until `.read()` returns an empty string.

Comment: More efficiently meaning the process takes less time or more efficiently meaning the process eats less processing power?  Also, what's a buffer, and do I have to import something to gain access to those functions?

Comment: @IanZane: More efficiently by not eating as much memory. A buffer is just a chunk of the file held in memory to copy from the file-to-read to the file-to-write-to. Yes, you need to import `shutil`, as you would with all libraries.

Answer (score 3):

One caveat is that `.read()` isn't necessarily guaranteed to read the entire file at once, so you must make sure to repeat the read/write cycle until all of the data has been copied. Another is that there may not be enough memory to read all of the data at once, in which case you'll need to perform multiple partial reads and writes in order to complete the copy.

Comment: I didn't know .read() has a memory limit, thanks for the help.

Comment: @IanZane I don't think ``.read()`` has a memory limit but rather the computer you are using.

Comment: Oh, so reading the file in parts should only be necessary when moving files larger than the amount of idle RAM I have?  So stuff like pictures should be fine, but videos or other stuff like that might need to be done partially?

Or is it not actually related to file size or RAM, but to some other limit?

Comment: @IanZane: Allocating hundreds of megabytes just to copy a file is seen as slightly pathological behavior for an application, so you may want to keep it to a reasonable value.

Comment: I didn't know it allocated that much memory, I assumed it only allocated as much memory as the file size, so for images, allocating a few megabytes would be acceptable, but I understand that it wouldn't scale.

Comment: It is limited to file size, but files can get very large.

Answer (score 0):

> So, from what I've read, if you want to make a copy of a text file, you can just open and read it contents to a variable, then write this variable to a different file.
>   I've tested it out with images, and it actually seems to work. Are there downsides to this method of copying that I'll run into later, and are there any file types it specifically won't work for?

If you open both files in binary mode, you read with .read(), and write with write(), then you get an exact copy. If you use other mechanisms, you could strip out line endings or encounter troubles, in particular when you work cross-platform.

From the docs

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows
>   makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
>   characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
>   is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data
>   is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that
>   in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading
>   and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to
>   the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary
>   files.

In any case, use other approaches to file copy, like the ones suggested by others.