# Can't copy compressed files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to copy various files for several times with a specific name and I wanted to make the process automate. This is my python code:

```
number_of_copies = int(raw_input("enter number of copies "))

copy_number = 1

infile = raw_input("file to be copied ")
new_file = raw_input("What's the name of the new file?")
extension = ".fastq"
indata = open(infile)

file_to_copy = str(indata.read())

while copy_number < number_of_copies:

    copy = open(new_file + "-" + str(copy_number) + extension, 'w')
    copy.write(file_to_copy)
    copy_number = copy_number + 1    

indata.close()
copy.close()
```

In this case I know the extension of my file so I have hard coded it and I just change that variable in the script accordingly. 
The script works fine with my .fastq files (basically text files) but as soon as I try it on a fastq.gz file (compressed) the copy has size 1kb (from original >300 Mb size). I believe the problem is with the fact that the .gz is a compressed file but I don't know how to solve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

p.s. of course, when I try it with the .gz files I change the "extension" variable as well.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html, I think better to use function  shutil.copyfile

Comment: Is this on Windows?

Comment: Yes, taken from the  documentation 'On Windows, file owners, ACLs and alternate data streams are not copied.'

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627465/copying-files-with-python

Comment: Thank you! I had a look at that! Pretty interesting and useful indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, using `shutil` is more efficient.

You're getting errors because your OS does [newline translation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) on text files. So to use the above code correctly on all files you need to open them in binary mode, eg

```
open(infile, 'rb')
```

and

```
open(new_file + "-" + str(copy_number) + extension, 'wb')
```

Here are the Python 2 docs for [open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466036/4014959) has a handy table of the standard file modes.

Comment: @Faber No worries. I've added a couple of Python 2 links to my answer. BTW, you should seriously consider moving to Python 3 because Python 2 won't be supported after 2020.

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('recipes.tar.gz', 'r') as raw_file:
    with open('new.gz', 'w') as new_file:
        new_file.write(raw_file.read())
```

I think your question is can't open the ".gz" extension file, so I try it, does not happened any problem. Of course if your file is very lage, it will be another problem.